# Please How do I make an Element slide-in, user selects choice from drop-down, then it slides out

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please I need an element on my page to slide-in automatically 3 seconds after page is opened, and then slide-out after user chooses their preferred choice from the dropdown menu (which is the Element). I want the slide-in/slide-out effect to be from the right-hand side of the page.

The dropdown menu particularly is the 'Google Translate Element', which I have styled to my desired appearance, and I want this to slide in 4 seconds upon page lunch and after user chooses desired language, it slides out.

Below is the code for the styled Element

```
 /*google translate Dropdown */
#google_translate_element select{
 background: rgba(246,237,253,0.92) !important;
 border: none !important;
 color: rgba(54,58,173) !important;
 width: 115px !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;
 padding: 5px 5px !important;
 font-size: 11.8px !important;
 position: absolute !important; 
 margin-top: 84px !important; 
 margin-left: 232px !important;
}
.vl {
    position: absolute !important;
    border-left: 3.7px solid green !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    margin-top: 67px !important;
    margin-left:351px !important;
}
 /*google translate link | logo */
.goog-logo-link,.goog-te-gadget span,div#goog-gt-{
   display:none!important;
}
.goog-te-gadget{
   color:transparent!important;
   font-size:0;
 }
 /* google translate banner-frame */
.goog-te-banner-frame{
 display:none !important;
 }
#goog-gt-tt, .goog-te-balloon-frame{
   display: none !important;
}
.goog-text-highlight { 
    background: none !important; 
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<div class="vl"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Johnny blee Rowland, from the looks of it, you are trying to achieve this with just CSS. And although CSS has transition effects, the actions you described are done with Javascript.
You should improve your code's format to be more "consumable" to the reader. (eg. removing extra whitespace).
Also, be sure to search SO for slide-in effects with Javascript. Devs are lazy and no one is going to write that up for you just like that :D.

Comment: A hint, you have two actions to check. On page load and on form submit.
Google for CSS transition effect with Javascript.

Comment: @Zalom thanks, I've just done that. And also I really don't necessarily need it done with CSS. Any language, I'm very satisfied. So long I can achieve what I need, I will be glad. If JavaScript is the option, I'm going in for it gladly.

Comment: @Zalom I really need help sir. I would definitely appreciate please

Comment: Sorry mate, my company also needs my help, they are paying me to do these kinds of things :D. But as suggested, try digging more into the documentation. Javascript + CSS. Those are the basics.

Comment: @ChrisSpittles please can you help out

Answer (score 0):

To hide the element to the right you can:

1. Give it a css property `right` of less than zero and position absolute. This will hide the element to the right of the page. Be sure to make it `position:absolute`, and how much of it is hidden by the `right` property depends on the width of the element. If `width` is 2 px, don't set `right` to 50px, play with it till its correct.

To make it appear:

1. change it's `right` css property to 0 or more [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.php), that will put it back on the page.

To make it appear *after n seconds* since the user selects an option:

1. put an event listener on every selectable element in the dropdown (either individually or from it's parent element), this would presumably be a `onclick` listener.
2. When the event is triggered, set a `setTimeout` function with JS ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)) for whatever time you want to, with a callback to a function that updates the hidden element `right` property to more than 0, thus making it appear from the right

it would end up kind of like:

```
/*css*/
element {
  right: -15px;
}
/*js to show after 4 seconds*/
const showElement = () => {
  /*update css `right` property*/ 
}

let startTimeout = setTimeout(showElement(), 4000)

element.addEventListener('click', startTimeout())
```

Comment: It doesn't work @Z.Bent

Comment: I need more help if you don't mind. Nothing of that code works as I've tried